# Two Navigation Drawer on same Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to configurate two Navigation Drawers on the same activity, one from the left and the other from the right?

Comment: Yes: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-ui-regions

Comment: For the rest please ask a acceptable question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use drawer layout

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <!-- The main content view -->

   <FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp"
       android:background="#111"/>


   <ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="end"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="0dp"
       android:background="#111"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ALso check the documantation https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Make sure you are using toolbar not action bar

Comment: wow great thanks man!! `android:layout_gravity="end"` is awesome

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can add two ListView inside your drawer layout, one listview should have `gravity` `start` and other have `end`.

Answer (score 3):

yes

Can use two navigationdrawer

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context="PackageName.ActivityName">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrol_lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!-- your layout -->

</ScrollView>
<!-- First navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_main_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"/>


<!-- Second navigation drawer -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view_second"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

For maximum customization,
In your xml, you can use a FrameLayout as a container

```
   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Now in your Activity, you can replace it with any fragment

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.contDrawer, SideBarCustomerFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

Now for two users, you can create 2 different fragments, You can check my boilerplate code for reference

https://github.com/hamzaahmedkhan/AndroidStructure/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/structure/activities/HomeActivity.java

https://github.com/hamzaahmedkhan/AndroidStructure/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/android/structure/activities/BaseActivity.java